# Requesting JWT from ADFS 2016 using custom attribute

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, adfs, ws-trust

We are looking into a way to request a JWT token from ADFS 2016 via webservice call by sending a user UID, which is stored in a database or in AD LDS. The token should contain the full domain username as a claim. A C# service would request the token without user GUI interaction (UID provided by an ID card), and then forward it to an intranet web application.

Is this possible with OAuth 2.0 or WS-Trust 1.3 in ADFS 2016, and what steps would be involved?

Right now I have tried using OAuth 2.0 (HTTP POST to /adfs/oauth2/token), but haven't been able to correctly configure ADFS (application groups, relaying parties, ...) and sending the correct HTTP parameters to even get a token by providing username/password.

It would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

A more detailed description of what we want to achieve:

Goal is to create a windows service which handles NFC card login and sends JWT with user information to arbitrary web applications.

1. C# windows service reads card UID from a NFC card reader.
2. Windows service requests JWT from ADFS by providing card UID. That can be OAuth or WS-Trust, whichever works.
3. ADFS looks up card UID from a confidential database. The database entry also contains the username. It could then further enrich this data by finding the domain user in ADLDS.
4. ADFS creates token containing at least the domain user name and sends it back to the C# windows service. No user interaction with ADFS login screens required.
5. Windows service receives token and forwards it to preconfigured web application login handler.
6. Web application validates token signature and handles login.

The credential in this case would solely be the card UID. Is this possible with ADFS? If not, my backup plan would be to create the token directly in my windows service.

Comment: Can you describe the flow pattern in more detail before I can guide/help you? Do you have a credential for the user?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I added more details to the question.